# Entity Framework: Add column requires altering of Seed data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, seeding

first off, I'm pretty certain that this must have been asked before but have been unable to find an exact answer via googling, so please bear with me.

I have inherited a code first entity framework project which uses migrations.  I've added a (non-nullable) column to a table and I need to insert values into this column for all existing entries - which are not the default value:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.QuestionType", "Duplicated", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: false));
    Sql("UPDATE dbo.QuestionType SET Duplicated = 1");
}
```

However there was originally some seed data added to this table:

```
context.QuestionTypes.AddOrUpdate(
                e => e.Name,
                new QuestionType() { Name = QuestionTypeNames.INTERVIEWER});
```

which means that the update statement is immediately overwritten by the data in the call to the Seed method (called after each migration).

My questions are:

1. Is it 'safe' to simply add the extra value into the Seed data (or will this cause everything to break for earlier migrations where the new column doesn't exist on the database).
2. Alternatively is there any way to prevent the Seed method from running after this migration (and all subsequent migrations).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework is great, but to be able to use it effectively, I'm afraid we really have no choice but to be diligent in making sure that the migrations and the seed method are in sync and work well with each other.

1. Yes, if you put the new value in the seed (ie. `new QuestionType() { Name = QuestionTypeNames.INTERVIEWER, Duplicated = true}`), this will cause systems which do not have the latest migration applied to break. This is because the seed method will be looking for the `Duplicated` column but will not find it.
2. No, I don't think there is a way to do this, at least not automatically. One solution is this: since you have access to the `context` object in the seed method, you can just query the database to check if the particular migration already exists. You can then wrap the specific seeder for `QuestionTypes` in an `if` statement, utilizing the result of the earlier query.

Comment: thanks for confirming this - I hadn't thought of checking to see whether the migration had been applied, sounds like a workable approach.  Having looked in more detail at the data added in the Seed method there's some data which shouldn't be there anyway (hard-coded passwords etc..) so it might turn out that my best bet is just to remove the data from the Seed method entirely...

Comment: Duplicated will always exist because the migrations are applied before the Seed() is run.